# ¿Cómo agregar enteros a una lista de python usando un método en una clase?

Tags: python, lista

Estoy comenzado a aprender python y es el primer lenguaje de programación que uso. Ocupo agregar elementos a una lista de python usando un método creado en una clase, cuando agrego los elementos el único que se guarda es el último y no la lista de 10 elementos, ¿cómo puedo lograrlo? Pueden ayudarme por favor.

```
class MyPowerList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.List = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.List.append(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("This program is for Lab2")
    print("Class start here")
    power = MyPowerList()
    for i in range(1, 11):
        a = int(input("Please provide the integer"))
        power.add_item(a)

    print(a)
```

Comment: Estás en SO En español traduce por favor

Answer (score 0):

Debes llamar a la propiedad `List` en vez de la variable `"a"` cuando das la salida con el `print`

Asi quedaria el código:

```
class MyPowerList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.List = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.List.append(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("This program is for Lab2")
    print("Class start here")
    power = MyPowerList()
    for i in range(1, 11):
        a = int(input("Please provide the integer"))
        power.add_item(a)

    print(power.List)  #Esta es la modificación
```

Saludos

Comment: Funciona!!! muchas muchas gracias, soy novato y aprendo por mi cuenta por que me encanta programar. Gracias de vuelta.

Comment: Juan si la respuesta te ayudo considera marcarla como aceptada